# Deleting directories inside directories

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage, directory

I know that if you want to delete a directory you have to delete all of it's files first.

However if you want to delete a directory which contains empty sub-directories, do you have to delete those sub-directories first? or can you just go ahead and delete the main directory?

Comment: Honestly, it would be a _lot_ faster if you try it instead of asking here and waiting for an answer. Just create a test project with test folders and do it, you'll see pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to delete recursively:

```
var path = Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\Temp\DeleteMe");
Directory.Delete(path,true); // true for recursive
```

This should delete everything including files if you have the proper permissions.

Answer (score 3):

[Directory.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f.aspx) set the recurse flag to true, should do the job, no need to empty them first.

```
Directory.Delete(path, true);
```

I have just noticed that your tag refers to IsolatedStorage, in which case you will need to enumerate all the files and folders and delete as you go.
[How to: Delete Files and Directories in Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx3852wf.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Why check if it is empty or not when you are going to delete it anyway.

You can use the `Directory.Delete(yourpath,true)` method only if you are sure that there isn't any `readonly` file in the directory. else it will throw an `exception`. Instead you can use your own recursive method like this which will first mark the file as normal before deleting it.

```
public static void DeleteDirectory(string target_dir)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(target_dir);
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(target_dir);

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);
            File.Delete(file);
        }

        foreach (string dir in dirs)
        {
            DeleteDirectory(dir);
        }

        Directory.Delete(target_dir, false);
    }
```